# When mixing Blaze with React, is there a way to pass in code from the html file as a react child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an app that uses both Blaze and React, and we are slowly refactoring out the Blaze, but for the foreseeable future we will still have both.

I currently have a simple blaze template which has been changed into a React component. The template looks something like this:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    <div>
      <h1>{{someTitle}}</h1>
            <div>
                {{> Template.contentBlock}}
            </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The equivalent component currently looks like this:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    someTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.someTitle}</h1>
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The usage of the Template within another html file looks something like this:

```html
<div>
  Some Stuff
  <div>
    {{#myTemplate someTitle="Some Title"}}
      <div>
        More stuff within to go within my template
      </div>
    {{/myTemplate}}
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am currently trying to do is get rid of `myTemplate` and replace it with `MyComponent`. Usually this could easily be done by simply putting in `{{> React component=MyComponent someTitle="Some Title"}}`, but for this case since I have content within the template that probably has to be passed in as the component's children, I am not sure how it should be done.

So the question becomes, how can I pass in that content that is to be rendered within the template to the React component? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is there an error when putting the  `{{> React ...}}` block within `{{#myTemplate}}`?

Comment: Not but that beats the purpose of what I am trying to go: which is get rid of `myTemplate` and replace it's usage with the React component.

Comment: Interesting question! Have you already tried the "naive" (and ugly) approach of:
`{{> React ... children="some, hopefully static, html"}}`?